# How to update column b in table B based on results from column A in table A

Tags: c#, sql

I have a result verification app.  That matches candidates results against some API result and populates the data in a table called result, and inserts the candidate's data in table candidate with has a status column.

1. I want to use the CandidateNo to check result table to see if he has an unmatched result.
2. If true, update status on candidate table and set it to unverified
3. Otherwise set it to Verified

So, if a candidate has all his or her subjects = Match, then updateStatusOfCandidate(d.Candidate.CandidateNo, "VERIFIED");

```
enter code here
```

Else updateStatusOfCandidate(d.Candidate.CandidateNo, "Unverified");

```
 private void Process()
    {
        //read the data from csv
        List<CsvData> dataFromCsv = ReadCsvFile();

        //if we dont get any data, lets return and sleep...
        //if(dataFromCsv.Count < 1)
        //{
        //    return;
        //}

        //lets save the data to the db
        SaveCandidateData(dataFromCsv);

        //now lets get the data, from the db, we are doing this because we will need the id of the students
        List<Candidate> listFromDb = dbCtxt.Candidates.Where(c => c.Status == null).ToList();
        List<CsvData> nonMatchedData = new List<CsvData>();
        foreach(var l in listFromDb)
        {
            CsvData csvData = new CsvData();
            csvData.Candidate = l;
            csvData.Result = dbCtxt.Results.Where(c => c.CandidateNo.Trim() == l.CandidateNo.Trim()).ToList();

            nonMatchedData.Add(csvData);
        }

        //loop through the data we have 
        foreach(var d in nonMatchedData)
        {
            //lets make the api call
            var result = makeApiCall(d.Candidate.CandidateNo, Convert.ToInt32(d.Candidate.ExamDate), d.Candidate.ReferenceNo).Result;
            if(result == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            //lets convert the response to an object...
            APIResults apiResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResults>(result);

            //lets check the status of the result, 001 means its successful
            if(apiResults.StatusCode != "001")
            {
                updateStatusOfCandidate(d.Candidate.CandidateNo, "NOT FOUND");
                continue;
            }

            //lets do the compare it self 
            foreach(var s in apiResults.Result.SubjectCol)
            {
                //lets get the subject id, then use link to obtain the results...
                int subId = getSubjectId(s.Subject);
                if(subId == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //since we have the subject id, lets check the data we have from the csv to be sure its there
                var resultCsv = d.Result.Where(c => c.SubjectID == subId).FirstOrDefault();
                //if the data is not there, we continue
                if (resultCsv == null) continue;

                //if the data exist, lets now match it with the data we have from the csv to be sure the correct grade is there
                if (resultCsv.Grade.Trim().ToLower() != s.GradeScore.Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    updateStatusOfResult(resultCsv.ResultID, "UNMATCHED");
                    //if the result do not match, lets now set the status of the result column to be unmatched...
                }
                else
                {
                    updateStatusOfResult(resultCsv.ResultID, "MATCHED");
                }
            }
            updateStatusOfCandidate(d.Candidate.CandidateNo, "COMPLETED");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly you want the status of any `Candidate` that is in the `Result` table (as identified by the `CandidateNo`) to have a `Status` of `"Verified"`. And, any `Candidate` that is not in the `Result` table to have a `Status` of `"Unverified"`?

You can use a left join between `Candidate` and `Result` to find records that are in `Candidate` but not `Result`.

You can use an inner join between 'Candidate' and 'Result' to find records that are in both `Candidate` and `Result`.

I assume that `dbCtxt` is an `Entity Framework` `DbContext`, so for example...

```
private void SetUnverifiedCandidates()
{
   var unverified = dbCtxt.Candidates
      .GroupJoin(
         dbCtxt.Results,
         candidate => candidate.CandidateNo,
         result => result.CandidateNo
         (candidate, results) => new { candidate, results }
      )
      .SelectMany(
         joined => joined.results.DefaultIfEmpty(),
         (joined, result) => new { joined.candidate, result }
      )
      .Where(joined => joined.result == null)
      .Select(joined => joined.candidate);
      foreach (var candidate in unverified)
      {
         candidate.Status = "Unverified";
      }
      dbCtxt.SaveChanges();
}

private void SetVerifiedCandidates()
{
   var verified = dbCtxt.Candidates
      .Join(
         dbCtxt.Results,
         candidate => candidate.CandidateNo,
         result => result.CandidateNo
         (candidate, result) => candidate
      );
   foreach (var candidate in verified)
   {
      candidate.Status = "Verified";
   }
   dbCtxt.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but what I want is different.  Sorry if I made it look some other way.   In the result table, each candidate is supposed to have result for a minimum of 5 subject.  If all the results for a candidate match the response from my API, then candidate status in the candidate table should be updated as verified.  But if any of of the results do not match, the candidate status in the candidate table should be updates as unverified